# CakePHP - Two types of users to authenticate

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I would like to have two different registrations/logins in the same application. One for companies and one for employees because registering a company requires different information than registering an employee.

Is it possible to use the auth component to achieve two different registrations/logins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically change the AuthComponent's [configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/view/248/AuthComponent-Variables) in a [`beforeFilter()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/60/Callbacks). For example:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if (/* company login required */) {
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Company';
        // or:
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.type' => 'company');
    }
}
```